# Convert table cells to text-boxes with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a table, shown below:

```
<table id="paramsTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Value&nbsp;<span style="color: Blue; cursor: pointer; font-size: smaller;" id="editParamValues">Edit</span></th>
            <th>Type</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none;">1372</td>
            <td>providername</td>
            <td>BloombergFTP</td>
            <td>String</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none;">1373</td>
            <td>RateSetList</td>
            <td>1020</td>
            <td>String</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="display: none;">1374</td>            
            <td>BloombergServer</td>
            <td>CFC105</td>
            <td>String</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So now, that nifty little span, I have bound to this click event:

```
$('#editParamValues').live('click', function () {
      alert('true');
});
```

Getting the alert, it works fine. However, I don't want to alert, I want that binded method to change all of the cells that are in the `value` column to become textboxes filled with whatever their value is, so the user can edit them.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
$('#editParamValues').click(function () {
    $('tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).html(input);
    });
});
```

Comment: This is great! but this cannot revert back when click outside.

Answer (score 3):

You don't even need Javascript/jQuery:

```
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><input type="text" value="My Thing"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
input {
 border:none;

}
input:active {
    border:1px solid #000;
}
```

...just use CSS to style the input to look like a span.

Comment: this will remove border for all the input fields. What if i need to remove border for particular input fields?

Comment: This stuff is really cool...!!! But how to apply ":active" particular input fields?