# Change table cell from span to input on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to change the table cell from 'span' type to 'input' on click and then back to 'span' on blur but it isn't working as given in here:

[Convert table cells to text-boxes with JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445223/convert-table-cells-to-text-boxes-with-jquery)

here is the javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#assets').click(function () {
                $('tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
                    var html = $(this).html();
                    var input = $('<input type="text" />');
                    input.val(html);
                    $(this).html(input);
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

and here is the document body

```
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <table id="assets">
            <tr>
                <td class="asset_name"><span>Name</span></td>
                <td class="asset_value"><span>ast1</span></td>
                <td class="asset_name"><span>Location</span></td>
                <td class="asset_value"><span>Loc-1</span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="asset_name"><span>Name</span></td>
                <td class="asset_value"><span>ast2</span></td>
                <td class="asset_name"><span>Location</span></td>
                <td class="asset_value"><span>Loc-2</span></td>
            </tr>
        </table>​
    </div>
</body>
```

using jQuery 1.7.2

What's wrong here ? Please help !

Thanks!!

Update: only need to change the cells with class='asset_value' and only one cell at a time not all. Also, it should change back to span on blur..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#assets').on('click', 'span', function() {
        var $e = $(this).parent();
        if($e.attr('class') === 'asset_value') {
            var val = $(this).html();
            $e.html('<input type="text" value="'+val+'" />');
            var $newE = $e.find('input');
            $newE.focus();
        }
        $newE.on('blur', function() {
            $(this).parent().html('<span>'+$(this).val()+'</span>');
        });
    });
});​
```

this will change single cell on click and revert back to span on blur.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `replaceWith()` method, `html()` method empties the selected element and appends html markup to it, try the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#assets').click(function () {
            $('tr td:nth-child(3)').each(function () {
                var html = $(this).html();
                var input = $('<input type="text" />');
                input.val(html);
                $(this).replaceWith(input);
            });
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RBGME/5/)

---

As the `replaceWith` method changes the structure of the markup, you should delegate the events for the generated markup, you can use the `on` method, try the following:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#assets td', function () {
                var html = $(this).text()
                var input = $('<input type="text" />');
                input.val(html);
                $(this).replaceWith(input);
                $('#assets input').focus();
        });

        $(document).on('blur', '#assets input', function(){
            $(this).replaceWith('<td class="asset_value"><span>'+this.value+'</span></td>')
        })
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RBGME/34/)

Comment: In the demo:it works fine on first click, but goes weird when clicked again.

Comment: you should use var html = $(this).text(); instead of var html = $(this).html();

Comment: @user723438 yes, i had used `eq()` method, instead of `nth-child`, try the updated demo.

Comment: @Raminson thanks!! the updated demo looks great, but help! I need to change only the clicked table cell not all of them.

Comment: @Raminson Thanks again!!, exactly like I wanted but as I said I need to change only one.

Comment: @user723438 which one? you can use `eq()` method `td:eq(0)` selects the first td and `td:eq(4)` selects the fifth one, for example.

Comment: @Raminson the one which is click, none other.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully, this will help you: http://jsfiddle.net/RBGME/19/

HTML:

```
<div id="content">
    <table id="assets">
        <tr>
            <td class="asset_name"><span>Name</span></td>
            <td class="asset_value"><span>ast1</span></td>
            <td class="asset_name"><span>Location</span></td>
            <td class="asset_value"><span>Loc-1</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="asset_name"><span>Name</span></td>
            <td class="asset_value"><span>ast2</span></td>
            <td class="asset_name"><span>Location</span></td>
            <td class="asset_value"><span>Loc-2</span></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Sample CSS:

```
td { border: 1px solid #aaa; height: 30px; text-align: center; width: 100px; }
input, input:hover, input:focus { width: 100px; height: 30px; box-sizing: border-box; outline: none; background-color: #eee; }
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#assets tr td:nth-child(3)').click(function () {
        var html = $(this).html();
        var input = $('<input type="text" />');
        input.val(html);
        $(this).replaceWith(input);
    });
});?
```

Comment: Hey, its only changing the 3rd columns! nice styling done though :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right way
try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#assets').click(function () {
       $(this).find("span").replaceWith(input);
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('td').click(function(){
$(this).children('span').html('<input type="text">');
})
```