# POST values from inline edit

Tags: ajax

I used this code from
[Change table cell from span to input on click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11882693/change-table-cell-from-span-to-input-on-click)-
The replace one for inline edit now i want to post values through ajax and i am not sure how.
I just want to post the comments the users have edited and update them on the database
This is how i got so far:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comments.php",//to update the comments
        data: "data"

                });
```

Not sure what to put next. Is it possible to post values when user click out of input area? and does the data have to be `serialize`?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "comments.php",//to update the comments
        data: {"comments":$("yourformId").serialize()},
        success:function(res)
         {
           //Do what ever you want 
         }

           });
```

And in your `comments.php` just `print_r($_POST)` will give you the posted array via ajax

If you use `form.serialize` you will get all the data from the form you submitted

Comment: thanks for the reply i just want to post the comments to mysql