# Setting focus on first td cell with input in table

Tags: jquery, input, focus

I am having trouble setting focus on the first td cell with input box in the table. I change the cell content to input using solution from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6445223/convert-table-cells-to-text-boxes-with-jquery). Now I want to set focus on first input box.
My table structure look like this

```
<table id="knowledgeTreeTable" class="custom">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th class="">Who are the services being provided for?</th>
      <td class="">
        <input type="text" style="width: 97%;">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     .....
    </tr>
    ..... 
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#knowledgeTreeTable tr:nth-of-type(1) input").focus();
});
```

CSS pseudo-class `element:nth-of-type(n)` selects the nth element of its type in the document.
Elements separated by spaces mean a relation parent-child. So the code says something like

"Select an input whose parent is the 1st of its type and is child of an element with id *knowledgeTreeTable*"

[About pseudo-classes](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp)

Answer (score 1):

Asumming you're using jquery, you could use something like this:

```
$('#knowledgeTreeTable input').first().focus();
```